# Metro Style App: How to call a C# method from javascript code running in a webview control

Tags: c#, javascript, webview, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to implement the UI of my metro app using a Web View. Then, HTML/JS/CSS code will run inside it. The idea is to isolate that pure JS code from WinRT and Metro SDK. Aditionally I want to code in the same Metro app a C# API layer which will be consumed by the JS inside Web View. When the UI needs to use native code ( e.g. call to WinRT components ),   UI code running inside webview should call my C# methods.

Could someone give me an example about How call a C# method from javascript which is in a web view for a Metro app.
Thanks,
Hugo.

The walkthrough  you told me use a JavaScript project as a client and It has a reference to Windows Runtime Component developed in C#. (WinMD file) 
Instead of having a metro Javascript project,   I want to develop a Metro Style App using  a  C# project as client. It will contains a Web View which is the container of my UI .  This project will have a reference to Windows Runtime Component developed in C#. (WinMD file)
The idea is that the javascript running inside web view invokes methods from WinMD file, but unfortunately I could not call a method from WinMD from javascript running inside a Web View.

Comment: FYI, there's a great set of articles on Windows 8 in this month's (well, the edition still on the newstands) PC Magazine:  http://www.maximumpc.com/article/how-tos/install_windows_8_today  http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/8_things_we_love_about_windows_898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted the exact same question here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/fa0db73d-66db-4330-bf24-644703e9265b

The answer to your question should be here:

- [Creating Windows Runtime Components in C# and Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and here:

- [Walkthrough: Creating a simple component in C# or Visual Basic and calling it from JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)